# Is it possible to write these Protractor expectations using no continuations?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, webdriverjs

Using `protractor` and `jasmine(wd)` we want to check that a table on the web page contains expected values.  We get fetch the table from the page using a CSS selector:

```
var table = element(by.css('table#forderungenTable')).all(by.tagName('tr'));
```

We then set our expectations:

```
table.then(function(forderungen){
...
    forderungen[2].all(by.tagName('td')).then(function(columns){
        expect(columns[1].getText()).toEqual('1');
        expect(columns[5].getText()).toEqual('CHF 277.00');
    });
});
```

Is it possible to change this code so that we don't have to pass functions to `then`, in the same way that using `jasminewd` means that we don't have to do this? See [this page](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/webdriver-vs-protractor), which states:

> Protractor uses jasminewd, which wraps around jasmine's expect so that you can write:

```
expect(el.getText()).toBe('Hello, World!')
```

> Instead of:

```
el.getText().then(function(text) {
    expect(text).toBe('Hello, World!');
});
```

I know that I could write my own functions in a way similar to which `jasminewd` does it, but I want know if there is a better way to construct such expectations using constructs already available in `protractor` or `jasminewd`.

Comment: forderungen is german => one forderung is one row in the table

Comment: Sorry @alecxe, I 'd been waiting for more answers to see if anything better came along and then I forgot to accept it :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually call `getText()` on an `ElementArrayFinder`:

```
var texts = element(by.css('table#forderungenTable')).all(by.tagName('tr')).get(2).all(by.tagName('td'));

expect(texts).toEqual(["text1", "text2", "text3"]);
```